Drawing a rectangle on a tkinter canvas isn't working
I'm trying to draw a simple rectangle on an image placed inside a canvas in tkinter, but it's not drawing. There's no errors.
is it because I'm placing the image not with canvas.create_image? because I'm drawing the image inside a frame and I'm placing the frame inside the canvas. It's the only way of opening the full image with scrolling feature.
Here's the code:
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

root = tk.Tk()

# Tkinter widgets needed for scrolling. The only native scrollable container that Tkinter provides is a canvas.
# A Frame is needed inside the Canvas so that widgets can be added to the Frame and the Canvas makes it scrollable.
canvas = tk.Canvas(root)
fTable = tk.Frame(canvas)
hor_scroll_bar = tk.Scrollbar(root)
ver_scroll_bar = tk.Scrollbar(root)

# Updates the scrollable region of the Canvas
def updateScrollRegion():
    canvas.update_idletasks()
    canvas.config(scrollregion=fTable.bbox())

# Sets up the Canvas, Frame, and scrollbars for scrolling
def createScrollableContainer():
    canvas.config(xscrollcommand=hor_scroll_bar.set,yscrollcommand=ver_scroll_bar.set, highlightthickness=0)
    hor_scroll_bar.config(orient=tk.HORIZONTAL, command=canvas.xview)
    ver_scroll_bar.config(orient=tk.VERTICAL, command=canvas.yview)

    hor_scroll_bar.pack(fill=tk.X, side=tk.BOTTOM, expand=tk.FALSE)
    ver_scroll_bar.pack(fill=tk.Y, side=tk.RIGHT, expand=tk.FALSE)
    canvas.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, side=tk.LEFT, expand=tk.TRUE)
    canvas.create_window(0, 0, window=fTable, anchor=tk.NW)

# Adding an image 
def addNewLabel():
    img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file="test.jpg")
    tk.Label(fTable, image=img).grid(row=0, column=0)
    canvas.img = img
    canvas.create_rectangle(0, 0, 100, 100, fill="blue")
    # Update the scroll region after new widgets are added
    updateScrollRegion()

createScrollableContainer()
addNewLabel()

root.mainloop()

Thank you

"is it because I'm placing the image not with canvas.create_image? because I'm drawing the image inside a frame and I'm placing the frame inside the canvas. " - yes. You can't draw on top of windows.

canvas.create_rectangle(0, 0, 100, 100, are hidden behind Label widget.  So, it is small rectangle. So set this canvas.create_rectangle(0, 0, 240, 310, So you will see rectangle.

The rectangle is drawn on the canvas, not the image inside the label.  Note that widget put into the canvas using .create_window() will always has higher z-order than other canvas item created by .create_rectangle(), so the rectangle is covered by the label.
You can simply use .create_image() to put the image into the canvas instead and then you can draw the rectangle over the image.  The canvas is scrollable as long as the size (either width or height) of the image is larger than the size of the canvas.
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

root = tk.Tk()

canvas = tk.Canvas(root)
hor_scroll_bar = tk.Scrollbar(root)
ver_scroll_bar = tk.Scrollbar(root)

# Updates the scrollable region of the Canvas
def updateScrollRegion():
    canvas.config(scrollregion=canvas.bbox("all"))

# Sets up the Canvas and scrollbars for scrolling
def createScrollableContainer():
    canvas.config(xscrollcommand=hor_scroll_bar.set,yscrollcommand=ver_scroll_bar.set, highlightthickness=0)
    hor_scroll_bar.config(orient=tk.HORIZONTAL, command=canvas.xview)
    ver_scroll_bar.config(orient=tk.VERTICAL, command=canvas.yview)

    hor_scroll_bar.pack(fill=tk.X, side=tk.BOTTOM)
    ver_scroll_bar.pack(fill=tk.Y, side=tk.RIGHT)
    canvas.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, side=tk.LEFT, expand=tk.TRUE)

# Adding an image
def addNewLabel():
    canvas.img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file="test.jpg")
    # draw the image
    canvas.create_image(0, 0, image=canvas.img, anchor=tk.NW)
    canvas.create_rectangle(0, 0, 100, 100, fill="blue")
    # Update the scroll region after new widgets are added
    updateScrollRegion()

createScrollableContainer()
addNewLabel()

root.mainloop()

